# I'm getting a "Failed to parse time string" PHP error in Assets when trying to open the file information

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, php-errors

I'm getting the following PHP error in the console when trying to open up the image information:

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message: DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (@1.376583824E+12) at position 11 (4): Unexpected character</p> <p>Filename: libraries/Localize.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 290</p>
```

This happens within an entry, in File Manager, on an existing image and a newly uploaded image.

Running EE 2.6.1 and Assets 2.1.4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Everything but the Edit file option works. Upgrading Assets from 2.1.3 to 2.2.2 didn't help either. I'm only experiencing it on production server, which runs PHP 5.2.9-0.dotdeb.2 whereas staging works fine and it's running PHP 5.4.4-14.